# Clojure and Java interop : functions that return void

Tags: clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm trying to wrap Java Apache Maths 3 into Clojure but I'm facing a problem I do not understand.

Here is the javadoc :

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/javadocs/api-3.3/index.html

The method `addValue` adds a value to the object but returns void. I imagine there is some inner data inside this object.

In Java, I would do :

```
regression.addValue(1,2);
```

I defined functions in Clojure to wrap it :

```
;;----------Simple regression object builder----------

(defn simple-regression []
  (SimpleRegression.))

;;----------Add points----------

(defn add-point
  ([reg [x y]]
   (.addData reg (double x) (double y)))
  ([reg x y]
   (.addData reg (double x) (double y))))

(defn add-points
  ([data reg]
   (let [x (data :x)
         y (data :y)
         d (zipmap x y)]
     (map (fn [[k v]] (add-point reg k v)) d)))
  ([x y reg]
   (let [d (zipmap x y)]
     (map (fn [[k v]] (add-point reg k v)) d))))
```

The functions work fine when I use it separately in a repl.

I then defined a full wrapper :

```
(defn lin-reg 
  ([data & {:keys [type] :or {type "simple"}}]
   (let [reg (simple-regression)]
     (do (add-points data reg)
         (cond (= type "simple")
                 [(.getSlope reg) (.getIntercept reg)]
               (= type "extended")
                {:params [(.getSlope reg) (.getIntercept reg)] :r (.getR reg) :r2 (.getRSquare reg) :significance (.getSignificance reg)}
               (= type "full")
                {:params [(.getSlope reg) (.getIntercept reg)] :r (.getR reg) :r2 (.getRSquare reg) :significance (.getSignificance reg) 
                 :conf-intervals [(.getSlopeConfidenceInterval reg) (.getInterceptConfidenceInterval reg)] :params-sse [(.getSlopeStdErr reg) (.getInterceptStdErr reg)] 
                 :sse (.getSumSquaredErrors reg) :ssto (.getTotalSumSquares reg) :ssm (.getRegressionSumSquares reg) :cross-products-sum (.getSumOfCrossProducts reg)}
               :else
                 (println "regression type can only be : simple, extended or full"))))))
```

Code does not work (returns [NaN NaN] so that it means that the values have not been added), confirmed when I try (.getN reg) = 0
If I try it separately, I mean first

```
(def reg (simple-regression))
(add-points {:x [1 2 3] :y [0.1 0.2 0.3]} reg)
[(.getSlope reg) (.getIntercept reg)]
```

No problem, all works.

But inside the function, no. I tried many versions, one with a

```
_ (add-points data reg)
```

I have the impression that inside the functions, points are not added. It is the same if I copy paste the `do`.

Is there a more general Java mechanism I am missing like that the object cannot change inside a function ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map` and `zipmap` are lazy so when you use them in `do` and don't ask them to return actual values or force them (using `doall` or `dorun`) so all the elements are realised and all the side effect happen (e.g. calling `.addData` is a side effect changing some state) your function passed into `map` won't be called at all. When you use those functions in REPL, the result printing will try to render the result of `map` operation and thus realise the lazy seq.

If you don't need the actual result from `map` but just want the side effects to be applied, you might want to use `doseq` instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, looks like I'm missing a lot of knowledge about Clojure. I solved the problem with a doall since it's not for big computation but I will consider using doseq after !

Comment: you have been bitten by "the lazy bug", it only bites when you aren't looking ;-)